# The response time of GetObjectMetadataAsync is prolonged when the API receives a higher volume of concurrent requests

Tags: amazon-s3

The initial response time for the GetObjectMetadataAsync call exceeds more than 2 minutes, but subsequent requests show a gradual reduction in response time.

Reproduction Steps
Create a Web API, that validates the given file exists in the S3 Bucket

```
[HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Get(string fileName)
 {
     try
     {
         var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
         stopwatch.Start();
         using var client = new AmazonS3Client("AccessKey", "SecretKey", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
         GetObjectMetadataRequest request = new()
         {
             BucketName = "{bucketName}",
             Key = $"{fileName}"
         };
         _ = client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(request).Result;
         stopwatch.Stop();
         _logger.LogError(" Total time taken to complete" + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
         return Ok(true.ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return BadRequest(ex.Message);                     
     }
 }
```

Create a console application to make a concurrent to validate whether the file exists or not

```
public class AWS
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Validate().Wait();
    }
     public static async Task Validate()
     {
         List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
         /*Generate the 500 file names which exist in S3Bucket */
    
         List<Task> payloads= new List<Task>();
         foreach (var file in fileNames)
         {
             payloads.Add(ValidateFileExists(Path.GetFileName(file)));            
         }  
    
         Task.WaitAll(payloads.ToArray());
     }
    
     private static async Task ValidateFileExists(string fileName)
     {
         var client = new HttpClient();
         var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7190/S3BucketProxy?fileName={fileName}");
         Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

The initial response time for the GetObjectMetadataAsync call exceeds more than one minute, but subsequent requests show a gradual reduction in response time.

2024-01-22 20:59:00,768 [1] INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Now listening on: https://localhost:7190
2024-01-22 20:59:00,782 [1] INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Now listening on: http://localhost:5084
2024-01-22 20:59:00,790 [1] INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-01-22 20:59:00,794 [1] INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Hosting environment: Development
2024-01-22 20:59:00,796 [1] INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime - Content root path: C:\Helper\S3WebAPI
2024-01-22 21:01:11,637 [25] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104113
2024-01-22 21:01:11,631 [22] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete **104113**
2024-01-22 21:01:11,586 [5] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete **104113**
2024-01-22 21:01:11,586 [11] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104113
2024-01-22 21:01:11,586 [12] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104113
2024-01-22 21:01:11,586 [13] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104118
2024-01-22 21:01:11,730 [16] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104114
2024-01-22 21:01:11,585 [17] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104117
2024-01-22 21:01:11,585 [21] ERROR S3WebAPI.Controllers.S3BucketProxyController - Total time taken to complete104117